# K2 Materials and Topics

Tags: asp.net, workflow, k2

I am a new K2 developer and I am looking for K2 materials  about below Topics

1. Introduction to K2 Blackpearl.
2. Feature of K2 Blackpearl.
3. How to design and deploy k2 Blackpearl workflows .
4. How to integrate k2 Blackpearl application/workflow with .net/asp.net.
5. What is k2 black pearl workspace .
6. How to connect to k2 Blackpearldatabase.And perform k2 Blackpearl database transaction .
7. How we can work on K2 mobility features

Can you help me to do that, I don't have any background on K2.

Comment: check out http://help.k2.com for all these information.

Answer (score 3):

K2 has a lot of documentation and it's very good. You can find most of the content you're looking for on the help.k2.com web site. The site has a lot of content regarding K2 Workflows, SmartObjects and Smartforms. If you look in the top menu (under K2 Blackpearl, K2 Smartforms or K2 Connect), you can find:

- Manuals/Documentation under Online Help
- KB articles under Knowledge Base
- Learning videos under K2 University

This is all very helpful if you want to get an idea of how to work with K2 or to search for specific content once you already know the tool. But I highly recommend you getting some K2 training before working on a project (there are also some training videos of some of the training modules). Like with any other development tool, it's very easy to get something wrong or to take much longer to do things than if you knew what you were doing. Just a friendly heads up.

Also, if you want an overview of what K2 is all about, you can find it here:
http://www.k2.com/blackpearl

Finally there is the community site: http://community.k2.com/ which is a community driven site. In there you can find lots of custom content created by other K2 community members, a forum, blog posts, among other things.

Hope it helps,

Gonçalo

Comment: There is no section called Online Help in k2.com now.

Answer (score 0):

K2 stores all of it's programming configuration in SQL Server.  You can search this information to overcome some of the deficiencies with the designer.

**Workflows**

Run this SQL against the K2 database - SELECT [Name],[Json] FROM [K2].[Designer].[Process]

Save the results as a CSV (trying to copy and paste the json column will not work as the copy buffer hits a hard limit).

You now have the contents of the workflow as K2 sees it, which can be searched using a text editor.

**Forms**

Run this SQL against the K2 database -

SELECT [Xml] FROM [K2].[Form].[AuditLog] where data = '8faa544a-1acb-407f-8648-d1ce7aa1b673' order by datetime desc

The guid in the SQL can be retrieved from the URL when editing the form.

You now have the contents of the form as K2 sees it, which can be searched using a text editor.